# Has anybody tested android telephony with mock-ril included in hardware/ril?

Tags: android, testing, mocking, telephony, ril

The codes of mock-ril were released with android codes. It could run, but only provide with basic function, like sim card state and signal. I don't know if google tests telephony with this code. I also searched for mock-ril in google, but found no useful information.  Has anybody used it before? What do you think about it for testing telephony?

Answer (score 0):

Its basically just a stub. You need to use the ril binaries for you specific device. You can grab them from your device if your rooted, or you can check online and see if CyanogenMod supports your device.

Comment: Yes, it's a stub. As we are fixing telephony's bug and developing some customize feature, we need a test suit to test our codes in telephony. We plan to use android unit test suit plus mock ril, but I have no idea about whether mock ril's framework is ok or not.